# why 2d integer array working for characters?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

I have declared a `2D int` array. but this is also working for characters.

```
int has[MAX][2];
void check(char* arr, int n) {
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            has[arr[i]][1]=0;       
     }
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
          has[arr[i]][0]=1;
          has[arr[i]][1]++;
     }
     cout<<has['i'][1];
}
```

Comment: If you are asking why  has['i'][1] gives an answer, it's because 'i' is converted to the ascii value, which is (dec) 105, so the result will be has[105][1]

Answer (score 4):

When you declare an array like this:

```
    int has[300][2];
```

And then you access its members like this:

```
    has['x'][3]
```

or

```
    has['i'][1]
```

You are using a character instead of a number for the array first index.

So, in the last example  'i', which is a char, is converted to its ascii value, which is (dec) 105, so the result will be:

```
  has[105][1]
```